# How can an AC source be connected in parallel with a DC one (through a capacitor) in a common-collector BJT configuration?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ac, dc, parallel

As far as I understand, voltage sources (regardless they are AC or DC) should never be connected in parallel, since they are not ideal and one would end up charging the other.

However, in the following common-collector BJT schmatics:

[image]

an AC voltage source (Vin) is connected in parallel with a DC voltage source (Vcc). Is this possible because C1 is preventing the DC component of Vcc to 'charge' Vin? If yes, that only works if we assume that Vcc > Vin, doesn't it? If Vin would be greater than Vcc, could Vin be charging-discharging Vcc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *an AC voltage source (Vin) is connected in parallel with a DC voltage
> source (Vcc)*

Not true - the AC source is capacitively coupled to a node of two resistors forming a resistor divider with Vcc and this is wholly different to connecting a pure voltage source to another pure voltage source.

> *If Vin would be greater than Vcc, could Vin be charging-discharging
> Vcc?*

There are bigger problems because if Vin were greater than Vcc it would stop the circuit working and may even damage the transistor.

Generally, when parallel connecting ideal voltage sources (whether AC or DC), you have to avoid infinities and that usually means using interconnection resistors.

[image]

Comment: Then, an AC coupling capacitor is just an application of high pass filters, isn't it? When connecting the circuit the first time, wouldn't there be a transient (when the C1 is empty) in which Vcc goes ground through Vin? Could you replace C1 by a resistor way bigger than R2 to achieve a similar result?

Comment: You could actually put Vin in series with R2 and providing there is a DC path to ground through Vin, it will avoid using C1. Other than that, yes it's a HP filter but Vcc won't short to ground because of R1 (red circle).